# I need an unique regex that requires at least on letter and disallows + and any form of blank space

Tags: regex

I broke it down to two, but I'm wondering if it's possible in one.

My two regex

```
/^[^\s+ ]+$/

/(.*[a-zA-Z].*)/
```

Comment: `/^[^+\s]*[a-z][^+\s]*$/i`

Answer (score 2):

Why not both?

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^\s+]+$
```

Uses lookahead.

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^\s+]+$
^                        start of regex
 (?=.*[a-zA-Z])          make sure there is at least a letter ahead
               [^\s+]+   make every character is not a plus or any whitespace character
                      $  end of regex
```

Notice how I changed your `[^\s+ ]` into my `[^\s+]` because `\s` already included the space (U+0020).

Comment: Lookaheads are not always supported. MySQL, RE2, XML Schema flavors do not support a lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
/^[^+\s]*[a-z][^+\s]*$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cK6yF5/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^+\s]*` - zero or more characters other than `+` and whitespace
- `[a-z]` - a letter (case insensitive - see `/i` modifier)
- `[^+\s]*` - zero or more characters other than `+` and whitespace
- `$` - end of string

This expressions only requires one letter, and there can be any number of characters other than a space and a plus on both sides of the letter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I'm not sure what you mean by "unique", though:

```
/^[^+\s]*[A-Za-z][^+\s]*$/
```

Comment: This is my solution (just without the modifier).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Uhm, we wrote our answers at the same time, and there's only one decent way to do this... I avoided using a modifier because it's generally faster to match against a specific character range (in many regex engines, I believe).

Comment: 4 minute difference is not *at the same time*. Anyway, suit yourself.

Comment: @Wiktor, my computer says it was less than a minute difference between your answers. Don't be so grumpy about it, some people type slower than others.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can attest that I'm fluent enough in regular expressions that copying your answer would actually take more effort on my part than giving an honest answer. Furthermore, answers don't show up immediately as one's typing, so it's not like I was there monitoring the page waiting for an answer to "steal". Stop acting so defensive.

Comment: What I mean is I do not post the same anwers that are already provided in the comments. Or answers.